# Can Netflix Hystrix be used without RAbbitMQ

Tags: jms, netflix, hystrix

The usage of Hystrix which I have seen (i.e. with Spring cloud) uses an AMPQ broker?
Can Netflix Hystrix be used without RAbbitMQ? i.e. with JMS?

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix can be used without AMQP. It roughly has 2 models of operating.

- pull model; Turbine retrieves the data by polling the data
- push model; Hysterix client push data to an AMQP broker

I am not aware of a way to use JMS instead of AMQP. So maybe the pull model would fit your needs.